# "users" microservice - using passport

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, oauth

I am developing a microservice for user management, which will be consumed by:

- other microservices
- an SPA app
- a native app

It needs to:

- authenticate users
- authorize users
- manage oauth tokens
- manage registration/login/logout/reset password/forgot password

And it will be a pure REST API (no forms).

So far, I have:

- installed/configured Laravel passport and Passport::Routes()
- configured a password-grant client
- these two combined allow me to hit the `oauth/token` endpoint in order to get a valid JWT token, and use it to call `api/user` with "auth:api" authentication, successfully.

For my next trick, I need to configure all the user-management endpoints above (registration/forgot password/etc), and I am trying to figure out the neatest way to do this. I am trying to avoid using 3rd party mods of Laravel (dingo, esbenp/larapi, etc), unless I have to.

This means that both the `Auth::routes()` and `Passport::routes()` need to be implemented. The `Passport::routes()` seem perfectly fine as they are. But the `Auth::routes()` are not designed for a REST API.

My thought at the moment, is that the neatest way to implement the standard user-management functionality without reinventing the wheel, is to reimplement the traits consumed by the controllers in the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth` namespace. These are:

- Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers
- Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RedirectsUsers
- Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers
- Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords
- Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins
- Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails

And because of the way php traits work this can be done selectively, only reimplementing necessary functions, like so:

```
class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    use SendsPasswordResetEmails, MySendsPasswordResetEmails 
    {
        // REPLACE THE HTML FORM WITH A JSON PLACEHOLDER
        MySendsPasswordResetEmails::showLinkRequestForm insteadof SendsPasswordResetEmails;
        // REPLACE THE HTML RESPONSE WITH A JSON RESPONSE
        MySendsPasswordResetEmails::sendResetLinkResponse insteadof SendsPasswordResetEmails;
    }
}
```

It's still totally terrifying, but it seems like the best way to avoid duplicating code. I would like to know:

- is this a good idea
- if anyone has any advice on how best to do this
- if there is any documentation on modifying auth traits
- and ideally, if anyone has done it before?

tbh, I haven't even started thinking about the authorization piece, but I assume this will sit on top of authentication.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a heads up, I appear to have done this successfully - login/logout/register/password-reset all appear to work, and errors return as JSON.  If I get enough responses I will write up a blog post.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the blog post, sounds interesting :)